# Does anyone know how to create a Visual Studio aspx formatting Rule for "Property Per Line"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Bar.aspx.cs"
MasterPageFile="~\Foo.Master" Inherits="Client.LineOfBusiness.System.Bar" %>
```

Does anyone know of a Visual Studio Formatter rule that will get ^ to be auto-formatted as:

```
<%@ Page    Language="C#" 
            AutoEventWireup="true" 
            CodeBehind="Bar.aspx.cs"
            MasterPageFile="~\Foo.Master" 
            Inherits="Client.LineOfBusiness.System.Bar" %>
```

Note that a tag specific rule for the Page tag is less than ideal, but if you know how to craft a tag specific rule to accomplish this same effect, it could be a building block for me to craft an ASP.NET formatting ruleset from.

However, I am specifically looking for any way to set a more global "single property per line" rule for the Visual Studio text view subsystem.

Free Extensions/Add-Ins that produce the same effect as well as manual walkthroughs are very welcome responses.  It drives me absolutely bonkers that the ASP.NET auto-formatting rules do such a crappy job out of the box of aligning aspx for source control.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there is no feature in-built in Visual Studio 2012 (not even 2013), that would do this automatically. The only tool that "might" help is ReSharper, but if it is possible, then the option is very hard to find :-) . I'm afraid you will not be able to achieve this easily...

But as far as my experience with ASP.NET goes, I usually didn't pay much attention to this header tag, it might be a little less beautifully formatted, but it is something that can be get used to.

Comment: I was using the Page tag for illustrative purposes.  I'm not looking to format just a Page tag like I have above. I want all of my properties to be forced to be vertically tab-aligned within a tag and a rule forcing only one property per line to provide clean integration with tfs source control.

If it's just not possible, that's fine. I just have a lot of old markup pages from other devs that are improperly formatted and I was looking for a quick way to auto-correct their brokenness.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible... But someone else here could have a tool (or app :-D ) for that ;-)